# Mocking sql.max() in golang using go-sqlmock

Tags: go, go-sqlmock

I am looking to mock up this query in my code (`"select max(a) from public.abc where id = %d"`)

The way I am mocking this line is

```
maxOfA := 1
maxOfARows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"a"}).AddRow(maxOfA)
suite.mock.ExpectQuery("select max(a) from public.abc co where id = \\$1").WithArgs(1).WillReturnRows(maxOfARows)
```

And I am seeing this error

```
Error:
    Query: could not match actual sql: "select max(a) from public.abc where id = 1" with
        expected regexp "select max(a) from public.abc where id = 1"
```

What is the right way to mock the max() such sql functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was that i wasnt wrapping up my mock query within (regexp.QuoteMeta()). wrapping up the query within the quotemeta did resolve my issue
Reference: https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#QuoteMeta

Not deleting this post hoping it to help someone like me.